# Power Query: Why do Text Filters Remove null Values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, database, power-query

### Problem Statement

I am using Power Query in Excel for Microsoft 365.

I have found cases where applying a text filter to a column matches ***null*** values. This results in undesired removal of rows. I have found a workaround for this, but I am trying to understand *why* this behavior is in place or if it is a bug.

The screenshot below shows my unfiltered data and the result of applying this M Language filter:

```
= Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each not Text.EndsWith([Column 2], "foo"))
```

[image]

By substituting ***null*** values into the filter's predicate, we get:

```
not Text.EndsWith(null, "foo")
not false
true
```

So, the "anteater" row should be kept (since that row's value for "Column 2" does not end in "foo"), **but the row is discarded**.

### Workaround

Suppose I change the filter as follows:

```
= Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each not Text.EndsWith([Column 2], "foo") Or [Column 2] = null)
```

In this case, we get:

[image]

This is the desired result.

### My Question

*Why* are rows with a ***null*** value in "Column 2" being filtered out by my first filter? Or, is this a bug?

### Edit to Add Demonstration of Selected Answer

Ron Rosenfeld's answer was instructive enough I thought I should add a demonstration of what he suggested I try to understand the behavior. When adding custom columns as Ron suggests, here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented (albeit well-hidden) behavior regarding behavior of *`null`* in comparisons.

You can see it if you add a custom column to your original table with the formula:

```
not Text.EndsWith([Column2],"foo")`
```

You will note this returns *`null`* whether you do or do not include the `not`.

And since `Table.SelectRows` only returns those rows which evaluate as *`True`*, it will not return the row containing a *`null`*

And your workaround is what you need to do, although you can shorten it by using the `coalesce` operator like this:

```
Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each not Text.EndsWith([Column2] ?? "x", "foo"))
```

The `??` works by evaluating the left side unless it is null, in which case evaluate the right side.